# JOIN three table and get specific result in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables as follows:

**`protocol`:**

```
+----+---------+------+----------+
| id | subject | date | location |
+----+---------+------+----------+
| 1  | sub1    | c1   | s1       |
| 2  | sub2    | c1   | s2       |
| 3  | sub3    | c3   | s2       |
| 4  | sub4    | c2   | s3       |
+----+---------+------+----------+
```

**`protocol_item`:**

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | protocol | body  |
+----+----------+-------+
| 1  | 1        | Hello |
| 2  | 2        | world |
| 3  | 2        | ok    |
+----+----------+-------+
```

**`protocol_participant`:**

```
+----------+-------------+
| protocol | participant |
+----------+-------------+
|  1       | Right 1     |
|  2       | part 72     |
|  2       | Hello 3     |
+----------+-------------+
```

I want to select item from the `protocol_item` table where `protocol_item.protocol` = 2 :

```
+----+---------+----------+-------+-------------+
| id | subject | location | body  | participant |
+----+---------+----------+-------+-------------+
| 2  | sub2    | s2       | world | part 72     |
| 2  | sub2    | s2       | ok    | Hello 3     "
+----+---------+----------+-------+-------------+
```

I have tried below way:

```
select item.id 
  , item.protocol
  , item.body
  , p.subject
  , pp.participant 
from protocol_item item 
left join protocol p 
  on item.protocol = p.id 
left join protocol_participant pp 
  on pp.protocol = item.protocol 
where item.protocol = 2;
```

But it's showing 4 values. Where am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The results make total sense to me -- there are two matching items and each has two participants, so 2 * 2 is four rows.  What do you *want* to return.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It should be return two values. But i am getting 4 values. I think participant value is multiplied by protocol_item value. But don't why is this happening.

Comment: Can you try `left join protocol_participant pp on pp.protocol = p.id` instead of `left join protocol_participant pp on pp.protocol = item.protocol` ?

Comment: @Arulkumar Not working... https://prnt.sc/o0uqq8 in this screen shot i have 4 row in participant table that's why its showing every value 4 times. Without join participant table its working as i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT item.id, item.protocol, item.body, p.sub, pp.participant 
FROM protocol p 
    INNER JOIN protocol_item item ON item.protocol = p.id 
    INNER JOIN protocol_participant pp ON pp.protocol = item.protocol 
WHERE item.protocol = 2 GROUP BY item.id
```

Comment: getting multiple id value same as me.. see https://prnt.sc/o0uqq8 in this screen shot i have 4 row in participant table that's why its showing every value 4 times. Without join participant table its working as i want

Comment: @sumandas It's working but `participant` column is showing same value in all row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id as id
     , p.subject
     , p.location
     , pi.body
     , pp.participant 
  FROM protocol p 
  JOIN protocol_item pi
    ON p.id = pi.protocol 
  JOIN protocol_participant pp 
    ON pi.protocol = pp.protocol 
 WHERE pi.protocol = 2
```

Am assuming the id you want in the joined table is p.id, in case you want protocol_item.id then it should be pi.id as id

Comment: Am assuming the id you want in the joined table is p.id, in case you want protocol_item.id then it should be pi.id as id